# What's wrong with this php foreach code? (merged array)

Tags: php, pdo

```
$db = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$database", $username, $password);

            $items = 'SELECT items FROM menus';
            $itemLink = 'SELECT itemLink FROM menus';

            $itemQuery = $db->query($items);
            $linkQuery = $db->query($itemLink);

            $fetchItem = $itemQuery->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            $fetchLink = $linkQuery->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

            $merged = array_merge($fetchItem,$fetchLink);

            foreach($merged as $key=>$value){
                echo "${key} =>  ${value} <br />";
            }
```

This is what it looks like in the database:

```
items   |itemLink
----------------------
Kill Bill|Kill Bill link
Preman  |Preman link
```

So, the expected output, or at least what I thought must be this:

```
    items => Kill Bill
    items => Preman
    itemLink => Kill Bill Link 
    itemLink => Preman Link
```

But the resulted output from the code is this:

```
items => Kill Bill
itemLink => Kill Bill Link
```

It's missing the other items and itemLink

So, how do I achieve the output that I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
        $fetchItem = $itemQuery->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $fetchLink = $linkQuery->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

This only fetches the first row of each resultset. You need `fetchAll`:

```
        $fetchItem = $itemQuery->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $fetchLink = $linkQuery->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

and adjust the rest of your code.

```
        foreach($merged as $entry) {
          foreach( $entry as $key => $value ) {
            echo "${key} =>  ${value} <br />";
          }
        }
```

**EDIT:** 
The call of `fetch` only retrieved the first row of the resultset, whereas `fetchAll` parses the complete resultset into an Array. So the Objects look like this afterwards:

```
Array(
  [0] => { 'items' => 'Kill Bill' },
  [1] => { 'items' => 'Preman' }
)
Array(
  [0] => { 'itemLink' => 'Kill Bill' },
  [1] => { 'itemLink' => 'Preman' }
)
```

`array_merge` concatenate both arrays to the following:

```
Array(
  [0] => { 'items' => 'Kill Bill' },
  [1] => { 'items' => 'Preman' },
  [2] => { 'itemLink' => 'Kill Bill' },
  [3] => { 'itemLink' => 'Preman' }
)
```

So we now have a two dimensional array. To traverse the values we need first to select each `$entry`, which is done in the outer `foreach` and can afterwards access the key/value structure in the inner `foreach`.

As pointed out in the other comment: If you want to preserve the connection between `items`and `itemLink`, you should change the query in the first place to

```sql
SELECT items, itemLink FROM menus
```

Comment: Now it's giving me this:
0 => Array
1 => Array
2 => Array
3 => Array
4 => Array
5 => Array

Comment: @MouseHello did you adjust the `foreach` like I said?

Comment: Sorry, didn't notice the foreach. It works now, how does it work?

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple [array_combine()](http://php.net/array_combine) function to do what you are trying to do now.

```
$merged = array_combine($fetchItem, $fetchLink);
```

This will make all the item from `$fetchItem` as keys to the item from `$fetchLink`.

Comment: The link between both values would be easier by just changing the query to `'SELECT items, itemLink FROM menus'`, though.